# Oracle 12.2.0 installation NLS_CHARACTERSET QUESTION

Tags: oracle

Im creating fresh database 12.2.0 on linux(RH7.6) but not with GUI (dbca). Im installing it from scripts and which in file i can set parameter NLS_CHARACTERSET to EE8MSWIN1250 in pre-install process so I don't have to change it after install.

Comment: You should almost always use `AL32UTF8` as database encoding.

Comment: I know but it has to be customized for EE8MSWIN1250 cuz data will be migrated from other database. Im preparing database for this data

Answer (score 2):

The characterset is provided as part of the [CREATE DATABASE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/CREATE-DATABASE.html) statement, not as a parameter.

[image]

> **Creating a Database: Example**
>
> The following statement creates a database and fully specifies each
>   argument:
>
> ```
> CREATE DATABASE sample
>    CONTROLFILE REUSE 
>    LOGFILE
>       GROUP 1 ('diskx:log1.log', 'disky:log1.log') SIZE 50K, 
>       GROUP 2 ('diskx:log2.log', 'disky:log2.log') SIZE 50K 
>    MAXLOGFILES 5 
>    MAXLOGHISTORY 100 
>    MAXDATAFILES 10 
>    MAXINSTANCES 2 
>    ARCHIVELOG 
>    CHARACTER SET AL32UTF8
>    NATIONAL CHARACTER SET AL16UTF16
>    DATAFILE  
>       'disk1:df1.dbf' AUTOEXTEND ON,
>       'disk2:df2.dbf' AUTOEXTEND ON NEXT 10M MAXSIZE UNLIMITED
>    DEFAULT TEMPORARY TABLESPACE temp_ts
>    UNDO TABLESPACE undo_ts 
>    SET TIME_ZONE = '+02:00';
> ```